# Is my approach to this android TABS design correct?

Tags: android, android-layout

I know I talked about the same thing in another thread but it was too confusing because of the many questions. I thought that here I would tell you the problem and my approach to it so I get your feedback.
I need your help with my application design. I am designing an application with 4 tabs (using tabhost ..etc). The 4 tabs will be identical in terms of layout (text views, buttons..etc) Except that the texts and color are different from a tab to another. Tab 1 feeds info to Tab2 and so on. How do you suggest I go about it? I will tell you what I am thinking of doing and PLEASE correct me before  I start as I am sure you guys are way more experienced than me :)

- Create `layout.xml` that has the layout design such as text views,
  buttons ..etc

In Java, I would create ONE activity for the whole thing and set the
the xml file as the content for each tab meaning that I would do
something like that:

```
th.setup();
for(int i = 1; i<5; i++){
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("Tab"+i);
    specs.setContent(R.id.layout);
    specs.setIndicator("Tab"+i);
    th.addTab(specs);
}
```

- I have a static variable (hash table or array) that contains the
  values of all the tabs so that everytime a tab is clicked, I load it
  layout with the correct text values and I set the background
  appropriately.

Does this sound right?

Ideally, I wouldve preferred if I can set the content of each tab and
then be able to get access to each tab and updates the values there.
So that when the tab is requested the values are there but I don't
think there is a way I can do especially with the fact I am using the
same layout (meaning same IDs for its elements) for all the tabs.

Any recommendations?